# On positive definite Matrices and being symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have the following Matrix $A$ given as:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}10&0.1&1&0.9&0\\ 0.2&9&0.2&0.2&0.2\\ 0.3&-0.1&5+i&0&0.1\\ 0&0.6&0.1&6&-0.3\\ 0.3&-0.3&0.1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Applying Gerschgorin's Theorem (details not necessary), I know for sure that all Eigenvalues of this Matrix are positive. In my professor's notes it says and I quote:

> If $\lambda_{i} > 0 $  for all $i=1,2,...,n$, then $M$ is called positive definite $<=>$ $M>0$

So I'd say, $A$ here is positive definite. Yet the solution tells me

> ... but having positive Eigenvalues is not sufficient for $A$ being positive definite. Since it is not symmetric, it will not be positive definite.

But there are for sure non-symmetric Matrices, that are positive definite. So I'm very confused here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By definition, a positive definite matrix is symmetric and has all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: @the_candyman This post says otherwise: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954167/do-positive-semidefinite-matrices-have-to-be-symmetric#:~:text=No%2C%20they%20don%27t%2C%20but%20symmetric%20positive%20definite%20matrices,of%20a%20non-symmetric%20positive%20definite%20matrix%20is%20%24%24M%3Dpmatrix%7B2%260%5C2%262%7D.%24%24

Comment: There are two definitions of positive definite that are in common use, as is noted on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-Hermitian_square_matrices) for "definiteness". It seems that the author of the solution in this case has a definition whereby positive definite matrices are necessarily symmetric.

Comment: @Rouben See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1555039/81360)

Comment: @Rouben By the way: for a non-symmetric matrix, positivity of (the real part of) the eigenvalues is necessary but is **not** sufficient for positive definiteness. For example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 6\\0 & 2}
$$
has positive (in this case, real) eigenvalues, but it is not positive definite.

Comment: @Rouben Note also that writing $\lambda_i > 0$ typically implies that $\lambda_i$ is a real number, which is different from the way you use the term "positive".

Comment: For many applications of a positive definite matrix you want the eigenvectors to be a complete set and to be mutually orthogonal, and this only is true if the matrix is symmetric as well.

Comment: General explanation, for those unfamiliar with the alternative definition. A (not necessarily symmetric) real matrix $A$ is sometimes said to be "positive definite" if it satisfies $x^TAx > 0$ for all non-zero $x$. This is equivalent to the condition that the "symmetric part" $\frac 12 (A + A^T)$ of $A$ is (symmetric and) positive definite.

Comment: @Rouben my definition is good for the real case. In general, when moving to the $\mathcal{C}$ world, symmetric is substituted by "the Hermitian is equal to the starting matrix$