# Closed and Bounded set over $2\times 2$ Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, optimization, convex-analysis

I want to check whether the given set is closed or bounded
$$S = \{X\in \mathbb R^{2\times2}:X\succcurlyeq0\text{ and trace(}X) = 1\}$$

I tried it in the following manner:

Let the generic matrix be
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\
x_3 & 1-x_1
\end{bmatrix},
Then we find the eigenvalues of the matrix to satisfy the P.S.D. condition. This gives us $\lambda^2-\lambda+(x_1-x_1^2-x_2x_3)=0$. Now, both the eigenvalues should be positive, and thus we get the condition $x_1-x_1^2-x_2x_3\geq0.25$

So now the set will be closed and bounded if the set S = $\{[x_1,x_2,x_3]\in\mathbb R : x_1-x_1^2-x_2x_3\geq0.25\}$ is closed and bounded.

But while calculating the critical point of the above function I found that it does not have any local/global minimum. The critical point is ($\frac{1}{2},0,0$) and results in the function value of 0.25

Can anyone give a hint about how to proceed further?

Is there any other method that is less calculation intensive?

Thanks!

Comment: What does $\succcurlyeq$ mean?  Are P.S.D. matrices always symmetric?

Comment: @kimchilover The symbol is for PSD. NO PSDs are not always symmetric.

Comment: @amaths: Then what does it mean to be PSD?

Comment: @PhoemueX PSD is when uTxu is non-nrgative. PSD matrix need not always be symmetric. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954167/do-positive-semidefinite-matrices-have-to-be-symmetric#:~:text=No%2C%20they%20don't%2C,(2022).

Answer (score 3):

The condition for your eigenvalues to be positive is not $x_1-x_1^2-x_2x_3\geq0.25$ and anyway, the positivity of the eigenvalues is not a sufficient condition for the matrix to be PSD.

The eigenvalues of a matrix $X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ are $\ge0$ iff their sum and product are, i.e. iff $a+d\ge0$ and $ad-bc\ge0$.

$X$ is PSD iff $a,d\ge0$ and $(b+c)^2\le4ad$, which is a strictly stronger constraint, even when $d=1-a$.

$$S=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&1-a\end{pmatrix}~\right|~0\le a\le1\text{ and }(b+c)^2\le4a(1-a)\right\}=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&1-a\end{pmatrix}~\right|~(b+c)^2\le4a(1-a)\right\}$$
is closed and unbounded:

- closed as the [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Preimage) of the closed set $\mathbb R_+$ by the [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R,\;(a,b,c)\mapsto4a(1-a)-(b+c)^2;$
- unbounded because $\begin{pmatrix}0&n\\-n&0\end{pmatrix}\in S.$

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you please show that the set is closed and bounded? I tried it doing like $(x+y)^2 \geq 4k(1-k)$ where $k \in [0,1]$ which is bounded but not closed

Comment: Done. I made a mistake, it is not bounded.

Comment: I slightly simplified the end of my answer. ([No need to say "thank you"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).)