# What does it mean for a function from R^n to R to be convex?

Tags: vectors, convex-optimization

I'm looking to determine when the function $f(\vec{x}) = k\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x} - \vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ is convex.

However, I'm not even sure where to start. For a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I would take the second derivative and set it positive, but I don't know if that still works for functions taking vector input.

Comment: We say $f$ is convex if given any two $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) y)\le \lambda f(x)+ (1-\lambda)f(y)$

Comment: Here's a [recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198198/if-a-in-rn-times-n-a-0-and-b-in-rn-then-the-function-frac1/3198240#3198240), which might be helpful.

Comment: There is also a sufficient condition for convexity involving second derivatives, see the first point here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables

Comment: @littleO That's exactly what I needed; if you write that as an answer I'll upvote and accept!

Answer (score 0):

Some useful facts:

1. The function $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$ is convex.
2. If you multiply a convex function by a nonnegative number, the resulting function is convex.
3. Any linear function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ is convex.
4. The sum of two convex functions is convex.

Using these rules, we can recognize immediately that if $k \geq 0$ then your function is convex.